# vimrc import file

Tags: linux, mercurial, vim

I have a repository of my home config files - http://hg.jackleo.info/home-configs

I noticed that my vim configuration is getting bigger and bigger (90% of commits is only related to vim) so I want to trow it to separate repository.

The problem is that since i'm using home-config repository at my actual home folder vimrc file is also in same place. If I would include subrepo to Vim configuration (folder .vim) I couldn't commit .vimrc file to that sub-repository.

Is there a way to simply write `import file_path_to_other_config` and hold exact configuration in .vim folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the source command in your vimrc:

```
source file_path_to_other_config
```

Here is the vim help page on source:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:source

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thought some while ago and came up with quite a simple solution. I have a `~/.vim/Makefile` which reads like this:

```
$(HOME)/.vimrc: Makefile vimrc.tmpl
    @cat vimrc.tmpl | sed 's\@@HOME@@\$(HOME)\g' > $(HOME)/.vimrc
```

With `.vim/vimrc.tmpl` being:

```
let $VIM = '@@HOME@@/.vim'

let $VIMRC = $VIM.'/custom.vimrc'

if filereadable($VIMRC)
  source $VIMRC
endif
```

I have everything in an extra git repository and when I work in a new system, I only have to clone the repository and call `make` inside `~/.vim`.